# Using mobile and CE cache together

Tags: cache, ce-cache

It seems that [mobile](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mobile) isn't compatible with [CE Cache](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-cache). Or the other way around. Can this be solved? When caching a page, you only see the desktop version of the template. The mobile template isn't loaded.

Thanks in advance! 
Diederik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to cache both versions with CE Cache. You just need to place a variable into the CE Cache id parameter that differentiates between the mobile and regular versions of the website. I haven't tested it but the following should work:

```
{exp:ce_cache:it id="page-{is_mobile}" seconds="3600"}
```

If the {is_mobile} global variable doesn't work you could also try with {segment_1}. According to the docs on devot:ee, it's meant to be prefixed with 'mobile__'.

> Because of the lack of extension hooks during the stage where Mobile works its magic, I had to hack into the segment variables array to make this work. Because of that, when using native EE routing (not with Pages or Structure), {segment_1} will also be prefixed with mobile__ in the mobile templates.

I've done this on a [Structure](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/structure) based site that used [Zoo Triggers](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-triggers). Zoo Triggers overwrites the segment variables behind the scenes which means caching doesn't work for similar reasons. The code I used in that instance looked like this:

```
{exp:ce_cache:it id="news_index-{triggers:segment_2}-{triggers:segment_3}-{triggers:segment_4}" seconds="3600"}
```